# Magento New installation - Table 'eav_entity_type' already exists

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to install Magento 1.8, however I got stucked in configuration step.

I got the following message: 500 Internal Server Error

Looking log file I could verify the following:

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'eav_entity_type' already exists"

But, here is the problem because it is a new installation and this table does NOT exist.

My Products versions are: W32 (test environment) PHP 5.4 MySQL 5.6.14 Magento 1.8.1.0, IE 9 FF 25.0.1 Chrome 31.0.1650

Could you please help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I finally got it. I did a totally new installation on Debian amd64. I installed only LAMP softwares and probably the FastCGI was avoiding to get success. It is necessary to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your database using phpMyAdmin and make sure there are no tables in there.
If there are, drop the user/table and re-create it anew and re-try the install wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all tabels or re-create databbase, and start installation again.